# How to ignore "Unable to connect to target host" error messages

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am using an SSH tunnel. It works fine but it gives me these messages regularly:

```
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Unable to connect to target host
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Unable to connect to target host
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Unable to connect to target host
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Unable to connect to target host
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Unable to connect to target host
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Unable to connect to target host
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Unable to connect to target host
```

The connection is working fine and I also want to actively use both the tunnel and the SSH connection in my terminal. So how can I suppress these warning messages?

Comment: Where are you seeing these messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-q` to the command you use to run ssh, from the man page:

`-q      Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed.`

[SSH man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/slogin.1?query=ssh&sec=1)